# how to send checkbox assigned Values to controller?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to insert Some Users in Some table and so I show them in view and set a checkbox for every one of them, now I want to send UserId to Controller.

I search a lot and see everyone is using checkboxfor which I don't want to use because it's not about the model.
and also some of the answers where assign integer values for the checkbox that I can't use because I want UserId

here is my code for showing Users in View

```
 for(int item = 0; item < Model.Count(); item++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[item].ApplicationUser.Email);
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[item].ApplicationUser.Name);
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[item].ApplicationUser.FName);
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[item].ApplicationUser.Mobile);
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[item].UserId);
       @Html.CheckBox("selectuser", new { id = "suid", UserId = Model[item].UserId });
    }
```

---

here is my code for sending CheckBox to controller

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#Saving').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var favorite = [];
                var UserIDs = [];
                $.each($("input[name='selectuser']:checked"), function () {
                    favorite.push($(this).val());

                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: '@(Url.Action("SaveWorkForUser", "ToDoList"))',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ values: favorite }),
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#message-container').html(result);
                    }
                });
```

Now I can see numbers of selected User in Controller but I want Their UserId

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int item = 0; item < Model.Count(); item++)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[item].ApplicationUser.Email);
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[item].ApplicationUser.Name);
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[item].ApplicationUser.FName);
        @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[item].ApplicationUser.Mobile);
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[item].UserId);
       @Html.CheckBox("selectuser", new { id = String.Format("id{0}", item), value = Model[item].UserId });
    }
```

Comment: Please describe why your answer solves the problem. More information can be found on [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)